# combine sets of factors in a dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

a question about combining factors with dplry. In the same df below I'd like to combine factors a and c into a new factor q per year, and sum their values. I know that I can group_by(years), but how do I also group_by q=a&c, l, b and y? (In reality, I want to combine three factor levels out of 12 by year.)

```
year  factor    value   
1977     a      564907 
1977     c      349651
1977     l     2852949  
1978     a      504028  
1978     1      413120  
1978     y     2553088 
1979     a      497766 
1979     c      789007 
1979     b     1567934
1980     a      346892
```

I want:

```
year  factor    value   
1977     q      564907 + 349651
1977     l     2852949  
1978     q      504028  
1978     1      413120  
1978     y     2553088 
1979     q      497766 + 789007 
1979     b     1567934
1980     q      346892
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would define a grouping variable like then `group_by(year, group)`.  If you have a lot of groups and want to code neat, perhaps `hash` helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. Not elegant but it works well I guess.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
       mutate(index = ifelse(factor %in% c("a", "c"), "q", as.character(levels((factor))))) %>%
       group_by(year, index) %>%
       summarise(sum(value))

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: year [?]

   year index sum(value)
  (int) (chr)      (int)
1  1977     b    2852949
2  1977     q     914558
3  1978     l     413120
4  1978     q     504028
5  1978     y    2553088
6  1979     b    1567934
7  1979     q    1286773
8  1980     q     346892
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with `recode` from `car`.  The group by operation can be done with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `recode` the 'factor' variable to convert the `levels` 'a' and 'c' to 'q', use that as grouping variable along with 'year', and get the `sum` of 'value'.

```
library(car)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(value=sum(value)) ,
         .(factor=recode(factor, "c('a', 'c')='q'"), year)]
#  factor year   value
#1:      q 1977  914558
#2:      l 1977 2852949
#3:      q 1978  504028
#4:      1 1978  413120
#5:      y 1978 2553088
#6:      q 1979 1286773
#7:      b 1979 1567934
#8:      q 1980  346892
```

Comment: Thanks, recode sounds nifty, but I'm going with the dplyr above since I don't have to load another library for the single task.